# SQL Query returns results for all districts but I need only one district to show up

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I am trying to get data for the people in `districtIDNum = 5` who have completed either `courseIDNum=11` or `courseIDNum=12`, but NOT both.

However, after I executed the query, it returned **ALL** districts.  What did I do wrong?  Please help, and thanks in advance!

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.Email, s.CourseIDNum
FROM People p
INNER JOIN Registration r
 on p.PeopleID = r.PeopleIdNum
INNER JOIN Section s
 on r.SectionIDNum = s.SectionID
INNER JOIN School sc
 on p.SchoolIDNum = sc.SchoolID
WHERE (s.CourseIDNum=11 AND s.CourseIDNum!=12)
  OR (s.CourseIDNum!=11 AND s.CourseIDNum=12)
  AND s.DistrictIDNum=5
  AND r.Completed='Y'
```

Here are the tables involved:

peopleID   FirstName   LastName   Email                   schoolIDNum
1               Esther         B                b@hotmail.com    33
2               Tommy        L                 l@hotmail.com     55

registrationID   peopleIDNum   sectionIDNum
22                    1                       40
23                    2                       41

sectionID   courseIDNum   districtIDNum
40             11                     5
41             12                     5

schoolID   districtIDNum
33             5
55             5

Comment: Why do you have both `s.CourseIDNum=11 AND s.CourseIDNum!=12` and `s.CourseIDNum!=11 AND s.CourseIDNum=12`?  Seems like it could be `(s.CourseIDNum=11 OR s.CourseIDNum=12)`

Comment: @David, thanks for the edit.  Can you kindly tell me how do I made my future scripts look like the edit you made?  Thanks.

Comment: code should be indented by 4 spaces.  `Inline code` can be achieved with back-ticks (the ~ key).  You can click Edit on your question to see what I did if you need.

Comment: @David - When I put (s.CourseIDNum=11 OR s.CourseIDNum=12), both of the courseIDs show up, whereby I only need to know if the people took one OR the other and not both.

Comment: A quick way of formatting text as code is to highlight it, then click the `{}` control immediately above the edit box.

Comment: RE: *I only need to know if the people took one OR the other and not both* FYI, added that new requirement to your question.

Comment: @Leigh How would it equal both?

Comment: @DavidStarkey - It would not ;-) I abbreviated their comment. The full version should make more sense.

Comment: Ah, why not use the XOR operator? `^` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190277.aspx

Comment: @DavidStarkey: Because it wouldn't be useful - a) because **bitwise** 11 XOR 12 is 8, and b) because for any given record, CourseIDNum will only have a single value.

Comment: @Mark But `s.CourseIDNum=11 ^ s.CourseIDNum=12` would return the correct results, wouldn't it?

Comment: @DavidStarkey: No, for the second reason I just mentioned; also, because **SQLServer** booleans are not treated as integers (unlike MySQL).

Comment: @Mark I must be misunderstanding order.  `s.CourseIDNum=11` and `s.CourseIDNum=12` would each result in 0 or 1 and then you would have `0^0`, `0^1`, `1^0`, or `1^1` which would give correct results (atleast according to MSDN article).  For b, the same logic would seem to apply to `s.CourseIDNum=11 AND s.CourseIDNum!=12` since `s.CourseIDNum=11` can equal ONLY 11, never 12 (and vice-versa).  Maybe I just need to run a few example queries and see it not working before it clicks.

Comment: @DavidStarkey: As I said previously: **SQLServer booleans are not treated as integers**. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/014de/121 - `a=11 ^ a=12` produces a syntax error; change the `^` to an `or` and the query will run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return only the people who took one or the other course but not both, try:

```
SELECT max(p.FirstName), 
       max(p.LastName), 
       max(p.Email), 
       max(s.CourseIDNum)
FROM People p
INNER JOIN Registration r
 on p.PeopleID = r.PeopleIdNum
INNER JOIN Section s
 on r.SectionIDNum = s.SectionID
INNER JOIN School sc
 on p.SchoolIDNum = sc.SchoolID
WHERE s.CourseIDNum IN (11, 12)
   AND s.DistrictIDNum = 5
   AND r.Completed='Y'
group by p.PeopleID
having count(distinct s.CourseIDNum)=1
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fceb1/1).

Comment: But the question was "I need only one district to show up" and `s.DistrictIDNum=5` was in the OP query.  Why would yours work and theirs not?

Comment: I ran this query and it returns 0 row.

Comment: @Esther: Can you add some sample data to your question? Are you sure that there are any people who completed one or the other course, but not both, in district 5? What happens if you remove the `having` clause?

Comment: @DavidStarkey: **was**, past tense - Little Bobby Tables' answer was correct until the additional requirement (to return only the people who took one or the other course but not both) was added.

Comment: As far as I read it the question continues to say "I need only one district to show up" and the OP query continues to contain `s.DistrictIDNum=5`.  The issue sounds more like the query returning records where `s.DistrictIDNum!=5` more then returning records that don't meet `s.CourseIDNum=11 XOR s.CourseIDNum!=12`

Comment: @Mark: I removed the having clause, no rows returned either.  Will send in some sample data.

Comment: @DavidStarkey: You're reading the query wrong - AND takes precedence over OR, so the conditions in the last two lines of the original query only apply where CourseIDNum is 12; if CourseIDNum is 11, the `where` clause evaluates as true, regardless of district number or completed status.

Comment: @Mark: Can I post my sample data under my original questions using edit?

Comment: @Mark Thanks for clearing that up.  Makes so much more sense now.

Comment: @Mark: I posted my tables for your review.  Thanks!

Comment: @Esther: I have tried my query with your data (with an added Completed column on Registration) and it returns both people - see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fceb1/1 .

Comment: @Mark: Indeed, the data are returned correctly.  Cool tool there!  I don't understand why it's not returning anything on my end?

Comment: @Esther: Some extra test data in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f773c/1 which also tests cases where registration is not Complete, or where a person is registered on both courses. Since you don't see any results even without the `having` clause, it sounds as though you have no people in district 5 who are on either course - to check, add `max(s.DistrictIDNum)` to the select clause, comment out the `AND s.DistrictIDNum = 5` condition, rerun the query and browse the results (assuming there are any).

Comment: @Mark: Did as you suggested and it returns everyone in ALL districts who completed 11 or 12.  However, the column for max(s.DistrictIDNum) is not returning any districtID.

Comment: @Esther: It sounds as though districtID is null for all qualifying sections, then (and therefore any query matching all your requirements will return no rows).

Comment: @Mark: You are absolutely correct!  I was looking at the Section table and the districtIDNum within it are null.  Thanks so much for your time!